# Send neighbor advertisement message with a network device

Tags: linux-device-driver

I send 2 bytes (0x10 0x10) with a socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM, 0), if I use a multicast address ff02::2, the message is:

3333 00 02 a0b0
 c0d0 e0f0 86dd 600
 00 0a 111 fe80
 00 00 00 a2b0
 c0ff fed0 e0f0 fe80
 00 00 00 2b0
 52ff feff ff2 f1d4
 3be 0a 81ef 1010

While I send to unicast address, instead of my real message, the socket send ICMP neighbor solicitation message. I have to reply with a neighbor advertisement, like this.

```
icmphReply.icmp6_type  = 0x88;
icmphReply.icmp6_code  = 0x00;
icmphReply.icmp6_router = 0;
icmphReply.icmp6_solicited = 1;
icmphReply.icmp6_override = 0;
```

How does sending the message through the network device?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For unicast to work, you need to determine the link layer address of the destination.  In IPv6 that's done with the neighbour discovery protocol.

When you send a packet to a destination that isn't in your neighbour cache, the kernel will do neighbour discovery.  The neighbour solicitation message you're seeing is the first step of that protocol.  After neighbour discovery succeeds, you'll send the packet to its destination.  If neighbour discovery fails, of course, the packet will be dropped.

In the multicast case, the mapping to link layer addresses is static and no neighbour discovery needs to take place.  Your packet gets sent immediately to the link layer multicast group.

Comment: ok, Thanks. But I have to implement the "neighbor advertisement" packet in the network driver? or the kernel do it by itself?

Comment: The kernel will do that for you.  Your device driver just has to pass packets and not care about what they look like (much).